# Converting an Indicator in TradingView from V2 to V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I am trying to convert this indicator "Hilo Activator" from v2 to v5. I did everything except the "stop", it kept saying the that it is undeclared identifier "series".

This is the original source code V2:

```
study(title="HiLo Activator", overlay=true)
length = input(3, minval=1)
displace = input(0, minval=0)
highsma = sma(high, length)
lowsma = sma(low, length)
swing = iff(close > highsma[displace], 1, iff(close < lowsma[displace], -1, 0))
mah = highest(high, length)
mal = lowest(low, length)
stop = iff(swing==1, mal, iff(swing==-1, mah, stop[1]))
linecolor = iff(stop < low, green, red)
plot(stop, style=line, linewidth=2, color=linecolor)
```

I tried using the automated pinescript complier to convert it, but it says the same problem that "stop" is not defined. I also changed all the updated variable and the iff function.

This is what I did until now (V5):

```
length = input.int(3, minval=1, group = GroupHiLo)
displace = input.int(0, minval=0)
highsma = ta.sma(high, length)
lowsma = ta.sma(low, length)
swing = (close > highsma[displace] ? 1 : (close < lowsma[displace]? -1: 0))
mah = ta.highest(high, length)
mal = ta.lowest(low, length)
stop = swing==1 ? mal : (swing==-1 ? mah : stop[1])
linecolor = (stop < low ? color.green : color.red)
plot(stop, style = plot.style_line, linewidth=2, color=linecolor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("HiLo Activator", overlay=true)

length = input.int(3, minval=1)
displace = input.int(0, minval=0)

highsma = ta.sma(high, length)
lowsma = ta.sma(low, length)

swing = 0
swing := close > highsma[displace] ? 1 : close < lowsma[displace] ? -1 : 0

mah = ta.highest(high, length)
mal = ta.lowest(low, length)

stop = 0.0
stop := swing == 1 ? mal : swing == -1 ? mah : stop[1]

linecolor = stop < low ? color.green : color.red
plot(stop, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, color=linecolor)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from v3, [Self-referenced variables are removed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#self-referenced-variables-are-removed).

You need to define the variable and then change its value with the `:=` operator.

```
stop = 0.0
stop := swing==1 ? mal : (swing==-1 ? mah : stop[1])
```